# Erro de: preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, phpmailer, envio-de-email

Determinada funcionalidade precisa do envio de e-mails e antes enviava normalmente, no entanto, agora aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /srv/disk35/4754145/www/meusite.com/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1922

Como resolver esse problema?

Abaixo transcrevo o trecho do arquivo mencionado na mensagem:

```
// Replace every high ascii, control =, ? and _ characters
//TODO using /e (equivalent to eval()) is probably not a good idea
$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',
                        "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes('\\1')))", $encoded);
break;
```

Comment: preg_replace é obsoleto desde a versão 5.5 e não suportado para  versão do php 7.0. Você pode alterar as configurações do seu display erros no php.ini para não exibir deprecated se sua versão for abaixo da 7.0 ou  substituir o uso da função nativa com : preg_replace_callback. A última solução é a que te indico. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 1):

Seu código deve estar usando uma versão antiga do PHP Mailer. Tente atualizar a mesma e verifique se o erro persiste.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Se estiver usando composer:

```
composer update phpmailer/phpmailer
```